# Regex: match lines missing word1 except they include word2

Tags: regex, preg-match

I'm looking for a regex which matches to certain URL's:

I want to match any URL except if they include the word "Koeln" OR if they contain the word "Karneval" (regardless if they contain Koeln or not).

Exaple:

1) `http://www.news.com/Report-Deutschland/Panorama/Deutschland/story.html`

2) `http://www.news.com/Koeln/Karneval/story.html`

3) `http://www.news.com/Koeln/Koelnaktuell/story.html`

1) and 2) should match. 1) because it doesn't include "Koeln" and 2) because it includes "Karneval"
3) should not match because it includes "Koeln" but not "Karneval"

I tried many different regex using positive/negative lookahead but none of them worked so far.

I plan to implement the regex with preg in PHP.

Comment: You'd probably be better of using simple string functions and some programming logic. Alaaf!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best approach here, but you can give this a shot and see if it works for you:

```
(http://.*?/Karneval.*$|http://www\.news\.com(?!/Koeln).*$)
```

I am basically just doing two expressions ... one to match `Karneval` and one that doesn't find `/Koeln` after `www.news.com`.

Here's a demo you can try:
<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aD6sL6/1)</kbd>

Hopefully this works for you or at least points you in the right direction.